# Latex alignment in the form-like for text in the header

Tags: horizontal-alignment, overleaf, alignment, latex3, text

**###### Research in YYYY**

Title--------: On the bla bla.

Speaker----: ……………………………………….

Room------: Zoom

How can we make something like this in latex? (I want to omit string "----" before : but the : to be aligned)

Answer (score 2):

You can use boxes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\presentationtitles}
\setlength{\presentationtitles}{4em}

\begin{document}

\noindent\makebox[\presentationtitles][l]{Title}: On the blah blah

\noindent\makebox[\presentationtitles][l]{Speaker}: Random Randofsky

\noindent\makebox[\presentationtitles][l]{Room}: Zoom

\end{document}
```

A similar result is possible using a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{} l @{ : } l }
  Title   & On the blah blah \\
  Speaker & Random Randofsky \\
  Room    & Zoom
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```